# How to ensure const static member initialization order?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having a problem with initialization order of a const static string class member. Some code:

constants.h

```
class Constants
{
public:
    // not used right now
    Constants& getInstance();

    const static std::string CONST_STRING;
};
```

constants.cpp

```
const std::string Constants::CONST_STRING = "my string";

Constants& Constants::getInstance();
{
    static Constants c;
    return c;
}
```

which is classic const static initialization (ignoring the `getInstance`). However, if I then try to use this constant elsewhere in another translation unit like this:

```
class OtherClass
{
public:
    OtherClass()
    {
        // tried uncommenting next line
        // Constants::getInstance();
        std::string str( Constants::CONST_STRING );
        std::cout << str;
    }
}

OtherClass obj;    // note global
```

the `CONST_STRING` is empty, i.e. it has been constructed but not initialized. I know that global initialization order is not defined across translation units and I'm guessing something like that applies here?

However, removing the commented out line that attempts to ensure that Constants is fully constructed before it is used (I don't believe it is needed but giving it a go....) still doesn't fix things.

Questions:

- How can I ensure const static members are fully initialized before anyone tries to use them?
- Is this the best C++11 way to have constants associated with a class? Is `constexpr` something that could be used here?

Comment: your Constants seems to implement a singleton pattern - why don't you make the string accessible through the singleton? i.e. make your string a member and initialise it in the constructor of the singleton.

Comment: See [this C++ FAQ entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use.html) on the static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: `getInstance()` has no bearing on the initialization of `CONST_STRING`. And `constexpr` is not an option because `basic_string` constructors are not `constexpr`. If you want to ensure a particular order, you could make `CONST_STRING` a function that returns a `const&` to a function local `static std::string`.

Comment: Could I use a constexpr with a char[]?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what are you looking for:

```
const std::string & GetConstantsString(){
    static const std::string CONST_STRING = "My string";
    return CONST_STRING;
}
```

As @AndreyT pointed out, literal type const static **only** are allowed to have in-class initializers so my option #1 will not work

Comment: I don't think option 1 works, and even if it does, it doesn't solve anything. And the return type in option 2 should be `std::string const&`

Comment: Er... Only *literal type* const static members are allowed to have in-class initializers. `std::string` is not a literal type. Your "first option" does not exist in the language.

Comment: @AndreyT Damn language forgot about that Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The initialization of globals within a translation unit is going to occur in hidden code within that translation unit. You can't control the order in which those bits of hidden code are going to be called.

Constants with basic data types can be initialized at compile time rather than run time, so this would work:

```
const char Constants::CONST_STRING[] = "my string";
```